# broadcast receiver before internet disconnects

Tags: java, android, sockets, server

I would like to know if on android it is possible to get a broadcast once the user clicks the wifi disconnect button to run a method BEFORE the device disconnects from the internet , I am already using a broadcast receiver to catch network change but it is executed after internet is disconnected I am using the code below :

```
public class InternetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable(context) && !isMyServiceRunning(MessagingService.class,context)){
        Intent i = new Intent(context,MessagingService.class);
        context.startService(i);
        Log.e("service started ","true");
    }

}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass, Context c) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context c) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager)  c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
}
```

I am using the code above to run the service once internet is connected but it is just an example

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I assume that you want to react to the user's click on the wifi disconnect button

You could check the state of the wifi connection by using Android's `WifiManager` which offers some possibilities to get information about your wifi environment and connection.

> Connectivity can be established or torn down, and dynamic information about the state of the network can be queried.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

Have a look at the following. I guess it'll be helpful to you.

> WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION Broadcast intent action indicating that Wi-Fi has been enabled, disabled, enabling, disabling, or unknown.
>
> int   WIFI_STATE_DISABLED Wi-Fi is disabled.
>
> int   WIFI_STATE_DISABLING Wi-Fi is currently being disabled.

Comment: heyRobin thanks for your answer, the thing is if I geta broadcast on wifi disabled will it be after internet has already been disconnected ? and if wifi disabling is sent before internet is disconnected this will still not assure that internet disconnection waits till the called method is done or will it??

Comment: I cant tell you how things will behave regarding the order, you have to try that. I don't think that it's possible to prevent android from disconnecting until a called method from within an app is executed. 

Is there a possiblity to achieve your goal in another way?

Comment: well the thing is my app is connected to a socket server and on internet disconnect I want to notify the server by sending a small package telling the server to close the socket on its side because if i dont the server doesnt detect that the open socket is invalid and will try to transmit data later :/

Comment: I have just tried using WIFI_STATE_DISABLING and at the moment it is being called the device has already lost network access